# Is there a way not to use the default tables in Django?

Tags: django

I am going to make a very simple Restful API. So there is no reason to use the default tables in Django.

- auth_group
- auth_group_permissions
- auth_permission
- django_admin_log
- etc..

Is it possible to define and use only the model (table) I want without using the default tables provided by Django?

Comment: Yes, remove the `django.contrib.auth` from the `INSTALLED_APPS`, etc. After all these models are not "hardcoded" into an *essential* Django installation, more in a default install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `auth` and `admin` application from your `INSTALLED_APPLICATION` list from your `settings.py`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin', # remove this line
    'django.contrib.auth', # as well as this
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

And do a fresh migration on the database.

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Does not work for me in djangorestframework==3.12.4 Django==3.2.2, gives error RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS, when I comment above lines. 
Also added -
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': None,